# Servlet Video streaming, but the video is not showing, audio is working

Tags: java, html, jpa, servlets, video

So I'm currently programming a java ee Backend, where I can store pictures or videos and I want to somehow stream the video from the backend to a client(internet browser) with the help of html5 < video> tag.The video part is not working it's just giving me a [blackscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVYM9.png),when I play the video, but the audio is playing. Image part is working well.

```
import com.dispway.restserver.facade.PlaylistEntryFacade;
import com.dispway.restserver.smallModel.SmallPlaylistEntry;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;


@WebServlet("entry")
public class PlaylistEntryServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @EJB
    PlaylistEntryFacade playlistEntryFacade;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        //entry-id
        String e_id = req.getParameter("e_id");
        //entry-type
        String type = req.getParameter("type");
        SmallPlaylistEntry entry = playlistEntryFacade.findById(Integer.parseInt(e_id));
        ServletContext context = getServletContext();
        String mimeType;
        ServletOutputStream outputStream;

        switch (type) {
            case "1":
                System.out.println("image-type");
                mimeType = context.getMimeType(entry.getFilename());
                if (mimeType == null) {
                    mimeType = "image/png";
                }
                resp.setContentType(mimeType);
                outputStream = resp.getOutputStream();
                outputStream.write(entry.getFile());
                outputStream.close();

                break;
            case "2":
                // NOT WORKING, I only get BlackScreen

                System.out.println("video-type");
                System.out.println(entry.getFilename());
                mimeType = context.getMimeType(entry.getFilename());
                if (mimeType == null) {
                    System.out.println("mime is null");
                    mimeType = "video/mp4";
                }
                System.out.println("MimeType: " + mimeType);
                resp.setContentType(mimeType);
                resp.setContentLength(entry.getFile().length);
                //getFile returns a byte[]
                BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(entry.getFile()));
                byte[] content = new byte[4096];
                int bytesRead;
                outputStream = resp.getOutputStream();
                while ((bytesRead = bufferedInputStream.read(content)) != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(content, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                bufferedInputStream.close();
                outputStream.close();
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Just to verify, did you try play that video file directly? VLC player?

Comment: yes it's working there with video and sound

Answer (score 0):

Sorry the video has the wrong codec, So the html `<video>` wasn't showing the video.